# RobotFramework force stop loading web page

Tags: javascript, selenium, robotframework

Issue i'm having is that my browser is navigating to a web-page which is consistently tailing log in html.
So RF is trying to wait until page is loaded. What i need to do is to stop this page. I can't do `Execute JavaScript      window.stop();` because i'm still stuck on the previous command(Go To ).

Here's my code:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource        my_resources.txt
Suite Setup     Open Browser to MySite and Login
Suite Teardown  Sign Out From MySite And Close Browser

*** Test Cases ***
Debugging TC
    Go To       https://example.com/var/log/wh/transcripts/440898.log
    Execute JavaScript      window.stop();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only work when page load strategy is set to none

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

cap = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
cap["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=cap)

driver.get("http://www.slowsite.com")

driver.execute_script("window.stop();")

driver.quit()
```

So you need to customize the browser launch in your robot script. I have not used Robot much but since it allows python extension it should be possible for you to achieve the same. But do know that the get operations won't wait for page load at all

Comment: Thank you! Found out that Selenium2Library already works with DesiredCapabilities - http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Open%20Browser